# maximum Difference between two zeros

Tags: calculus, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, periodic-functions

What is the maximum difference between the two consecutive zeros of the solutions of $y''+(1+x)y=0$ on $0\leq x<+\infty$? I have applied the Strum's comparison theorem (by comparison with $y''+y=0$), and I obtained this maximum as $2\pi$ but I think it may be $\pi$. Is it necessarily true? (According to the Strum comparison theorem we know that the solution of the above equation have many infinite zeros on $R$).

Comment: is $y=y(x)$ or $x$? what is your boundary conditions?

Comment: We have no boundary conditions, in strum Theorems, boundary condition dose not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Equation $$y''+y=0$$
has a general solution
$$y=a\cos t + b\sin t$$
Which obtain zero at 
$$t=\mathrm{atan2}\left(\pm\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}},\mp\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)=\begin{cases}
\arctan\frac{b}{\pm a}&\pm a>0\\
-\pi+\arctan\frac{b}{a}&\pm a<0,\mp b<0\\
\pi+\arctan\frac{b}{a}&\pm a<0,\mp b>0\\
\end{cases}$$
where $\mathrm{atan2}$ is a [special version of $\arctan$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) that work in all quadrants.

For example $a=1=b$ you have difference between zeros $=\pi$.

---

The situation for $y''+(1+x)=0$ is much more complicate if $y=y(x)$

$$y=c_1 \text{Ai}\left(-\sqrt[3]{-1} (-x-1)\right)+c_2 \text{Bi}\left(-\sqrt[3]{-1} (-x-1)\right)$$
See

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AiryFunctionZeros.html

http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/zamm.19960760714/abstract

Comment: Well, I know that $y''+y=0$ has the General Solution $y=a\sin(x-b)$ and so the zeros are $x=b+n\pi$ for all $n\in Z$ and we can see that the distance between zeros are $\pi$. What we can say about the distance between zeros for the solutions of $y''+(1+x)y=0$ on $0<x<\infty$?

Comment: for this you still have to answer if my question about $y$, whether it a function of $x$ or not? I guess yes.

Comment: Yes Michael, $y$ is a function of $x$.

Comment: see the $ $edit

Comment: what exactly you want me to see?

Comment: Excuse me. Thanks a lot Michael, please evaluate my discussion: Since, by Strum comparison theorem,  the solutions of $y''+(x+1)y=0$ has at least one zero between the zeros of solutions of $y''+y=0$, then  on any interval of length $\pi$ the solutions of $y''+(x+1)y=0$ have zeros such the distance between two successive zeros is at most $\pi$.

Comment: you have two zeros $z_1\in [\pi,2\pi]$  and $z_2\in [2\pi,3\pi$ 
there is nothing else that you know about  them so hypothetically it could happen $z_1=\pi+\epsilon$ and $z_2 = 3\pi-\epsilon$ so $z_2-z_1=2pi-2\epsilon$ so by that theorem you don't have anything closer then $2\pi$. You need $y''+4y=0$ which has zeros every $\pi/2$ or something like this

Comment: I found my answer and the maximum distance is $\pi$ since by Strum comparison theorem we have at least a zero for  solution of $y''+(x+1)y=0$ in "every" interval of length $\pi$. More details are discussed in: "An introduction to Ordinary Differential Equations" by Agarwal,  http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387712758,  (Lecture: 31).